# How to enumerate list of available Proxy IP & Port

Tags: networking

On office or any organizational network there will be proxies for connecting to internet, so how to enumerate list of available Proxy IP & Port if I connect my computer to that network? What I like to get is list of available Proxy IP & Port which I can use to connect to internet.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are authorized to connect to that network, those details are something that should be provided to you by the network administrator.  They may also be provided automatically through DHCP or [WPAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol).  Otherwise, besides attempting to sniff for existing network traffic (only if you're looking for trouble), there isn't really any way to do what you're looking for.

Comment: problem is the place I've connect is public and no one to ask for unfortunately